# Can json elements have different attributes?

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible that multiple json elemnts have different attributes?

Example:

```
"users":
         {
           "firstName": "John",
           "lastName": "Smith"
         },
         {
           "firstName": "John",
           "lastName": "Doo",
           "age": 34,
           "nick name", "JD"
         },
```

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: The biggest problem is "nick name"(comma) "JD".

Comment: @VLAZ never had to work with it before, and now I have to learn it in a short time. Therefore the stupid question. If the question offers no more value for others I'll delete it immediately.

Comment: Instead of deleting the question, accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But your example is malformed. See the correction below.

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doo",
            "age": 34,
            "nick name": "JD"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice the `:` after `"nick name"`? and `[...]` after `"users"` to denote an array.

Comment: Although having a space in your json, as in `nick name` parses, this is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's totally fine ,because here there is no blue print to follow while creating the objects you can have what ever the attributes you want.

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doo",
            "age": 34,
            "nick name": "JD"
        }
    ]
}
```

your source code should be like this .So inside every braces you have your separate json object available with it's attributes and values.Try to name attributes like nickName according to the camel case rather than having spaces in between.